# Error creating table: You have an error in your SQL syntax near 'order( order_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, user_id ' at line 1

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to create 2 tables in the same MySQL database with a PHP-script:
table 'user' with primary key 'user_id' and table 'order' with primary key 'order_id' and foreign key 'user_id' from the 'user' table (1 to many relationship).

Table user creates successfully without problems:

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE user(
    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    type ENUM('member','admin') NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    pass VARBINARY(32) NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    date_expires DATE NOT NULL,
    date_created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    date_modified TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
    UNIQUE (username),
    UNIQUE (email) 
    )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";
```

However, I am not able to create table order:

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE order(
    order_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    transaction_id VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL,
    payment_status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    payment_amount DECIMAL(6,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    payment_date_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (order_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (user_id)
    )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";
```

I get the following error:

```
Error creating table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order( order_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, user_id ' at line 1
```

Already checked the syntax and cannot find the mistake. Could you please advise what went wrong? Thanks a lot.

Comment: ORDER is a reserved word in SQL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to escape [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) like `order` with backticks

```
CREATE TABLE `order` ( ...
```

or better use another name instead.

Comment: Should I always declare my table 'names' in this way? My textbook didn't care so far...

Comment: @Neo83 - it's a good habit to get into, same with column names

Comment: @Neo83: That is up to you. Personally I find it confusing having backticks everywhere. Do as you like.

Comment: Just changed the table name to orders and now it works. Wouldn't accept 'order'. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Neo83: You used quotes around `order`. Backticks are different.

Comment: Ah, ok. Now I got it. I am using Robin Nixon's "PHP, MySQL, ..." and the syntax he is teaching is far from ideal... Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

order is keyword used by mysql like (select from tbl_name order by id ASC) so for escaping from using keywords you have to use quotes `` to avoid my sql error

so your query should by

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE `order` (
order_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
transaction_id VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL,
payment_status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
payment_amount DECIMAL(6,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
payment_date_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (order_id),
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (user_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";
```

enjoy :D

Comment: Just a note: *juergen d* posted an almost [same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/575376/juergen-d) 11 minutes ago. :)

Comment: ohh sorry i saw the answer without the reference to reserved words.. it's my fault, thank you